# Fetch list of all artists from iOS Media Library

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

I wish to fetch a `MPMediaItemCollection` or `NSArray` of all artists in a user's library. Here's my current code (which obviously doesn't work):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MPMediaQuery *artistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
    self.artistsArray = artistsQuery.collections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.artistsArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ArtistsCell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [(MPMediaItemCollection *)self.artistsArray[indexPath.row]   valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a list of artists, use `MPMediaItemPropertyArtist` rather than `MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName` for the media item property key.

Since your data source is using a `MPMediaItemCollection`, use the `representativeItem` property to get the artist title string for each collection.

Then set the `textLabel`'s text to the artist string.

```
MPMediaItemCollection *artistCollection = self.artistsArray[indexPath.row];
NSString *artistTitle = [[artistCollection representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
cell.textLabel.text = artistTitle;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked a treat!  How would you get a picture of the artist as the cell.imageView.image, though?  In the Music app, it shows pictures of the artists that aren't the album artworks.

Comment: If i want to get the artist artwork, how can i get that?